# Convert JSON to Different Json Format

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I want to convert my JSON Array in different manner.

My Actual array like as below :

```
[["Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM", 12], ["Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM", 30]]
```

And i want it like as below :

```
{
"data": [["Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM", 12], ["Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM", 30]]
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: this is ridiculously simple, please show what you have tried

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < length1; j++) {
                            dataXY.push([allVenues[i][j].date, allVenues[i][j].price]);
                        }

Comment: all you need is `var newData = { data: oldData}`. Creates a new object with one property `data` who's value is the original array

Comment: I have tried this but it'll return me an Object i want pure Json Array

Comment: But that's not what you asked for.

Comment: Object {data=[["Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM", 12], ["Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM", 30]]}

Comment: Sorry if i ask wrong question because i'm new in this one.

Comment: Well we can't help without knowing what you need specifically. Are you following some documentation somewhere that requires  specific format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element [["Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM", 12], ["Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM", 30]] is not a Json array, but simply an array.

To verify if your element is an array you may write in the browser console:

Array.isArray(yourarray)

To convert it to a JSON object you need simply create the object and to print you may use the JSON.stringify.

```js
var arr = [["Feb 18, 2016 11:53:49 AM", 12], ["Feb 18, 2016 11:54:49 AM", 30]];
var result = {'data': arr};
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thank you dear, this is what i'm looking for.